# Firebase CloudScheduler GCLOUD_PROJECT error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

This is my function with the configuration at the top, and the function at the bottom

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const Stripe = require('stripe')

const axios = require('axios')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://c6dcc.firebaseio.com'
})

exports.detectConnect = functions.pubsub
 .topic('detectConnect')
 .onPublish(async message => {
    console.log('THIS THING RAN')
    return null
 })
```

These are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mkdirp-promise": "^5.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0"
},
```

But firebase throws an error

```
Error: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT is not set.
at TopicBuilder (/srv/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/pubsub.js:43:19)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/srv/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:102:13)
at cloudFunction (/srv/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:151:20)
at Promise.resolve.then (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The error is also present when using [schedule-functions](http://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

Comment: Did you know that you can use a scheduled function and avoid the trouble of dealing with Cloud Scheduler directly? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: I get the same error response from firebase

Comment: Are you running in Node 10? Can you try switching your Node engine to "8" instead? Also make sure you're on the latest version of `firebase-tools`.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh My thought as well. Is something in the firebase-functions making use of GCLOUD_PROJECT?

Comment: @Alejov Please also make sure that you've fully updated the Firebase CLI and all of the dependencies in your package.json, and post your configuration by editing the question here.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the dependencies, the firebase cli, but same response.

Comment: How about an answer to Michael's question?  Could you edit the question to show your package.json?

Comment: I had firebase-functions ^2.2.0 and upgraded to ^3.3.0, and downgraded to node 8, and now it works, Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh you should post the response as a proper answer, so other people know how to approach this issue

Comment: @Edgardo It will be important to know which of the two changes was the one the fixed the issue.  Was it the version of firebase-functions (which was rather old - a whole major version behind, possibly before node 10 was available), or was it the target node runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running Node 10, please make sure you're on the latest version of `firebase-tools` and make sure you're deploying using the Firebase CLI. As of Node 10, the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable is no longer available by default.

If you're still running into problems, try changing your Node engine in `package.json` to `"8"` and see if you have more success.

Comment: Upgrading the `firebase-tools` module was enough for my project based on Node 10.